# the use of "as" in "as likely to'

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

> He, therefore, in proposing a great variety of employments, in manufactures or the care of plants and animals, allows for one third of women **as** likely to have a taste for masculine pursuits, one third of men for feminine.

I don't understand the usage of "as" at the end of this sentence; is it correct? Does “as” mean “owing to” here？

Comment: I understand it as something like "to be".

Comment: Or possibly short for "as being".

Comment: Either comment should be argued as an answer, not placed as comment.

Comment: _As_ in many uses is equivalent to a form of _be_; indeed, that may be a source.

Comment: What is this from and when was it written? It seems like an archaic use, although I might be getting that from the notions of masculine and feminine pursuits.

Comment: @Anton While it's strictly true that either Comment should be argued as an Answer, did you notice how many people here would rather get to the point than go to the trouble involved in preparing a formal Answer?

Comment: 'women as likely to have…' strikes me as ungrammatical. That Google didn't recognise the phrase says something, yet it strikes me as using the language of at least 150 years ago; possibly longer.

In this context, how do you see "as likely to have" as different to "as having" or "being likely to have"?

Answer (score 1):

First, undoing the conjunction reduction, this sentence is:

> [He] allows for one third of women as likely to have a taste for masculine pursuits, and he allows for one third of men as likely to have a taste for feminine pursuits.

As Huddleston & Pullum (2002) note, there is a "relatively unusual" construction" in which a verb takes a prepositional phrase with an ordinary object followed by a prepositional phrase with a predicative complement (p. 277, 280). One example of this is the verb *think,* as in "I think of it as indispensable."

Only a few verbs allow this construction; Huddleston & Pullum don't list "allow" as one of them. But I suspect that, when this book was written, *allow* could be used in this way; of course the sentence just means:

> [He] allows that one third of women are likely to have a taste for masculine pursuits, and he allows that one third of men are likely to have a taste for feminine pursuits.